# isotope Js: How an I remove an element with a specific id regardless of filter being used

Tags: javascript, foreach, jquery-isotope

I have the following elements on the dom that are being displayed and filtered by isotope.js

```
<div class="demos-filter">
    <div class="filter-button-group">
        <a data-filter="*">showAll</a>
        <a data-filter=".apples">topmenu</a>
        <a data-filter=".oranges">onepage</a>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="demos">

  <div data-index="0" class="demo oranges" data-level="1">
    //stuff here
  </div>

  <div data-index="1" class="demo apples" data-level="2">
     //stuff here
  </div>

</div>
```

Everything works great. However, I want to make isotope only show the results and filter those results by the data-level attribute value.

I saw that isotope allows you to [filter the results via a function](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) so I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                //start isotope layout
            $('.demos').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.demo',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                 filter: function() {
                    var bool = null;
                    //get the plan type from the dom

                    $('.demo').each(function(){

                        var planType = $(this).data('level')


                        if(planType == 1) {
                            bool = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            bool = false;
                        }
                        // return true to show, false to hide
                        return bool;
                        });
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

However, that's not working. How can I make isotope hide data on load and let the user use the isotope filters only on the data set previously filtered based on the data-level value?

UPDATE: I can't filter it via the source. It has to be done via isotope or js.